# Reduce and group records and replace a value in a field

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

For example purposes, I've selected only two repair references in the query.  The output shows a number of records per repair references.  For each repair there can be multiple sequences and for each sequence there is a trades person assigned to it (shown below):

```
╔══════════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Repair Reference ║ Tenant Name  ║ Job Sequence ║ Trade Code ║ Trade         ║
╠══════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╬═══════════════╣
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║            1 ║         41 ║ Plumber       ║
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║           10 ║         40 ║ Plasterer     ║
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║           11 ║         40 ║ Plasterer     ║
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║           13 ║         40 ║ Plasterer     ║
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║           14 ║         44 ║ Electrician   ║
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║           15 ║         44 ║ Electrician   ║
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║           17 ║         40 ║ Plasterer     ║
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║           18 ║         41 ║ Plumber       ║
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║           19 ║         41 ║ Plumber       ║
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║            2 ║         41 ║ Plumber       ║
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║           20 ║         32 ║ Joiner        ║
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║            3 ║         40 ║ Plasterer     ║
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║            5 ║         32 ║ Joiner        ║
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║            6 ║         40 ║ Plasterer     ║
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║            7 ║         40 ║ Plasterer     ║
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║            8 ║         32 ║ Joiner        ║
║         57342819 ║ MISS A GREEN ║            1 ║         40 ║ Plasterer     ║
║         57342819 ║ MISS A GREEN ║            2 ║         40 ║ Plasterer     ║
║         57342819 ║ MISS A GREEN ║            3 ║         33 ║ Painter       ║
║         57342819 ║ MISS A GREEN ║            4 ║         33 ║ Painter       ║
║         57342819 ║ MISS A GREEN ║            5 ║         33 ║ Painter       ║
║         57342819 ║ MISS A GREEN ║            6 ║         40 ║ Plasterer     ║
╚══════════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

The client only wants one record **displayed per Repair Reference** (example shown below) - I can do this using `Job_Sequence = 1`.  The problem I'm having is getting the `Trade` to show `Multi Trade` if there is more than one `Trade` type per `Repair Reference`.  This is what I'm struggling with.  Is it possible to look at all the `Trades per Repair Reference` and if there is more than one type, display the text *Multi Trade* otherwise if there's only one `Trade/Trade Code` for a `Repair Reference` then just use the trade as it is:

```
╔══════════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦════════════╦══════════════╗
║ Repair Reference ║ Tenant Name  ║ Job Sequence ║ Trade Code ║    Trade     ║
╠══════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║         57257795 ║ MISS L SMITH ║            1 ║         41 ║ Multi Trade  ║
║         57342819 ║ MISS A GREEN ║            1 ║         40 ║ Multi Trade  ║
╚══════════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Here's the SQL I've currently got:

```
SELECT
rhm_job_seqs.repair_ref AS "Repair Reference",
rhm_repairs.tenant_name AS "Tenant Name",
rhm_repairs.tenant_address1 AS "Tenant Address1",
rhm_repairs.tenant_address2 AS "Tenant Address2",
rhm_repairs.tenant_postcode AS "Tenant PostCode",
rhm_job_seqs.job_seq AS "Job Sequence",
rhm_trades.trade_code AS "Trade Code",
rhm_trades.trade_desc AS "Trade"
FROM (
RHM_REPAIRS
INNER JOIN RHM_JOB_SEQS ON RHM_REPAIRS.REPAIR_REF = RHM_JOB_SEQS.REPAIR_REF)
INNER JOIN RHM_OPERATORS ON RHM_JOB_SEQS.OPERATOR_ID1 = RHM_OPERATORS.OPERATOR_ID
INNER JOIN rhm_repair_type ON rhm_repairs.repair_type = rhm_repair_type.repair_type
INNER JOIN rhm_trades ON rhm_job_seqs.trade_code = rhm_trades.trade_code
INNER JOIN rhm_subareas ON rhm_repairs.subarea_no = rhm_subareas.subarea_no
INNER JOIN rhm_yhn_areas ON rhm_subareas.yhn_area_no = rhm_yhn_areas.area_no 
WHERE
NOT (RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE '9999Z' OR
RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE '9999z%' OR
RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE 'block' OR
RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE 'Block' OR
RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE 'Block%' OR
RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE 'BLOCK')
AND NOT (RHM_REPAIRS.JOB_PRIORITY LIKE 'I' OR RHM_REPAIRS.JOB_PRIORITY LIKE 'V')
AND (RHM_REPAIRS.REPAIR_TYPE LIKE '2' OR
RHM_REPAIRS.REPAIR_TYPE LIKE 'G' OR
RHM_REPAIRS.REPAIR_TYPE LIKE 'S' OR
RHM_REPAIRS.REPAIR_TYPE LIKE 'X')
AND RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_NAME <> 'VOID'
AND RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_NAME <> 'Void'
AND RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_NAME IS NOT NULL
AND RHM_JOB_SEQS.JOB_SEQ_STATUS <> 'X'
AND rhm_repairs.repair_completed BETWEEN SYSDATE-20 AND SYSDATE
AND RHM_REPAIRS.SUBAREA_NO <> '99'
AND rhm_job_seqs.repair_ref IN ('57342819','57257795')
AND rhm_job_seqs.job_seq = '1'
ORDER BY
RHM_JOB_SEQS.REPAIR_REF, rhm_job_seqs.job_seq
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try row_number()

```
 select * from (   
SELECT
    rhm_job_seqs.repair_ref AS "Repair Reference",
    rhm_repairs.tenant_name AS "Tenant Name",
    rhm_repairs.tenant_address1 AS "Tenant Address1",
    rhm_repairs.tenant_address2 AS "Tenant Address2",
    rhm_repairs.tenant_postcode AS "Tenant PostCode",
    rhm_job_seqs.job_seq AS "Job Sequence",
    rhm_trades.trade_code AS "Trade Code",
    rhm_trades.trade_desc AS "Trade",
    row_number() over (partition by rhm_job_seqs.repair_ref order by  rhm_job_seqs.repair_ref, rhm_job_seqs.job_seq) r
    FROM (
    RHM_REPAIRS
    INNER JOIN RHM_JOB_SEQS ON RHM_REPAIRS.REPAIR_REF = RHM_JOB_SEQS.REPAIR_REF)
    INNER JOIN RHM_OPERATORS ON RHM_JOB_SEQS.OPERATOR_ID1 = RHM_OPERATORS.OPERATOR_ID
    INNER JOIN rhm_repair_type ON rhm_repairs.repair_type = rhm_repair_type.repair_type
    INNER JOIN rhm_trades ON rhm_job_seqs.trade_code = rhm_trades.trade_code
    INNER JOIN rhm_subareas ON rhm_repairs.subarea_no = rhm_subareas.subarea_no
    INNER JOIN rhm_yhn_areas ON rhm_subareas.yhn_area_no = rhm_yhn_areas.area_no 
    WHERE
    NOT (RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE '9999Z' OR
    RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE '9999z%' OR
    RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE 'block' OR
    RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE 'Block' OR
    RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE 'Block%' OR
    RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE 'BLOCK')
    AND NOT (RHM_REPAIRS.JOB_PRIORITY LIKE 'I' OR RHM_REPAIRS.JOB_PRIORITY LIKE 'V')
    AND (RHM_REPAIRS.REPAIR_TYPE LIKE '2' OR
    RHM_REPAIRS.REPAIR_TYPE LIKE 'G' OR
    RHM_REPAIRS.REPAIR_TYPE LIKE 'S' OR
    RHM_REPAIRS.REPAIR_TYPE LIKE 'X')
    AND RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_NAME <> 'VOID'
    AND RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_NAME <> 'Void'
    AND RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_NAME IS NOT NULL
    AND RHM_JOB_SEQS.JOB_SEQ_STATUS <> 'X'
    AND rhm_repairs.repair_completed BETWEEN SYSDATE-20 AND SYSDATE
    AND RHM_REPAIRS.SUBAREA_NO <> '99'
    AND rhm_job_seqs.repair_ref IN ('57342819','57257795')
    AND rhm_job_seqs.job_seq = '1'
) where r = 1
    ORDER BY
    "Repair Reference", "Job Sequence"
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work - basically for each row I'd ask if there exist some higher job sequences:

```
SELECT
    rhm_job_seqs.repair_ref AS "Repair Reference",
    rhm_repairs.tenant_name AS "Tenant Name",
    rhm_repairs.tenant_address1 AS "Tenant Address1",
    rhm_repairs.tenant_address2 AS "Tenant Address2",
    rhm_repairs.tenant_postcode AS "Tenant PostCode",
    rhm_job_seqs.job_seq AS "Job Sequence",
    rhm_trades.trade_code AS "Trade Code",
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM RHM_JOB_SEQS job_seqs2
        WHERE rhm_job_seqs.repair_ref = job_seqs2.repair_ref
            AND rhm_job_seqs.trade_code <> job_seqs2.trade_code
            AND job_seqs2.job_seq > 1
    )
    THEN 'Multi Trade'
    ELSE rhm_trades.trade_desc
    END AS "Trade"
FROM RHM_REPAIRS
INNER JOIN RHM_JOB_SEQS ON RHM_REPAIRS.REPAIR_REF = RHM_JOB_SEQS.REPAIR_REF
INNER JOIN RHM_OPERATORS ON RHM_JOB_SEQS.OPERATOR_ID1 = RHM_OPERATORS.OPERATOR_ID
INNER JOIN rhm_repair_type ON rhm_repairs.repair_type = rhm_repair_type.repair_type
INNER JOIN rhm_trades ON rhm_job_seqs.trade_code = rhm_trades.trade_code
INNER JOIN rhm_subareas ON rhm_repairs.subarea_no = rhm_subareas.subarea_no
INNER JOIN rhm_yhn_areas ON rhm_subareas.yhn_area_no = rhm_yhn_areas.area_no 
WHERE
    NOT (
        RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE '9999Z' OR
        RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE '9999z%' OR
        RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE 'block' OR
        /** RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE 'Block' OR **/
        RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE 'Block%' OR
        RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_ADDRESS1 LIKE 'BLOCK'
    )
    AND NOT (RHM_REPAIRS.JOB_PRIORITY LIKE 'I' OR RHM_REPAIRS.JOB_PRIORITY LIKE 'V')
    AND (
        RHM_REPAIRS.REPAIR_TYPE LIKE '2' OR
        RHM_REPAIRS.REPAIR_TYPE LIKE 'G' OR
        RHM_REPAIRS.REPAIR_TYPE LIKE 'S' OR
        RHM_REPAIRS.REPAIR_TYPE LIKE 'X'
    )
    AND RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_NAME <> 'VOID'
    AND RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_NAME <> 'Void'
    AND RHM_REPAIRS.TENANT_NAME IS NOT NULL
    AND RHM_JOB_SEQS.JOB_SEQ_STATUS <> 'X'
    AND rhm_repairs.repair_completed BETWEEN SYSDATE-20 AND SYSDATE
    AND RHM_REPAIRS.SUBAREA_NO <> '99'
    AND rhm_job_seqs.repair_ref IN ('57342819','57257795')
    AND rhm_job_seqs.job_seq = '1'
ORDER BY RHM_JOB_SEQS.REPAIR_REF, rhm_job_seqs.job_seq
```

I also commented out a useless condition.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply to my question - much appreciated.  This looks like the kind of thing I am after.  The solution almost gave me what I wanted but I added 'and rhm_job_seqs.trade_code <> job_seqs2.trade_code' in between WHERE rhm_job_seqs.repair_ref = job_seqs2.repair_ref
            AND job_seqs2.job_seq > 1 and it has given me the results I need.  I've been out of the office for several days hence my late reply - but thanks very much for your time in helping me sort out my query/data extract.